# Named variable initialization in TF 1.0.0

Tags: tensorflow

I am having problems using `tf.variables_initializer` in the following case:

```
counter = tf.Variable(0, name='counter')
#1 counter = tf.assign_add(counter, 1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([counter]))
    #2 sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(counter))
    print(sess.run(counter))
```

As is, this snippet runs, but of course `counter` does not count. If the line marked `#1` is uncommented then I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'

The routine will run properly (and count) if the line marked `#2` is uncommented and the line with `tf.variables_initializer` is commented. But I can't use `tf.global_variables_initalizer` in my real code because I am restoring many variables from a checkpoint file.

What's the right way to initialize `counter` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the line `counter = tf.assign_add(counter, 1)` overwrites your `counter` variable. Does the below solve your problem?

```
    counter = tf.Variable(0, name='counter', trainable=False)
    increment_counter = tf.assign_add(counter, 1)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([counter]))
        print('Orig counter state:')
        print(sess.run(counter))
        _ = sess.run(increment_counter)
        _ = sess.run(increment_counter)
        print('Final counter state:')
        print(sess.run(counter))
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: Although I still don't understand why `tf.global_variables_initializer` worked with the original code while `tf_variables_initializer` did not.